# Logout in Angular OAuth2 OIDC and Spring Authorization Server

Tags: angular-oauth2-oidc, spring-authorization-server

I am using [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) library in my frontend application. The configuration is done the same way as shown in this [project](https://github.com/guidoffm/sample-angular-oidc-with-app-initializer), using `APP_INITIALIZER`.

Following is the `AuthConfig`:

```
{
    "issuer": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080",
    "redirectUri": window.location.origin + "/index.html",
    "clientId": "myapp-client",
    "scope": "openid profile myapp",
    "responseType": "code",
    "dummyClientSecret": "mysecret",
    "requireHttps": false
}
```

I have the following `routes`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/index.html',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  } as Route,
  {
    path: 'index.html',
    component: AutoLoginComponent
  } as Route,
  {
    path: 'protected',
    loadChildren: () => import('./protected/protected.module').then(m => m.ProtectedModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'forbidden',
    component: ForbiddenComponent
  }
];
```

The `AutoLogicComponent` is the same as shown [here](https://github.com/guidoffm/sample-angular-oidc-with-app-initializer/blob/master/app/src/app/auto-login/auto-login.component.ts).

For the OAuth2, I am using [spring-authorization-server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server).

The `.well-known/openid-configuration` returns:

```
{
  "issuer": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/oauth2/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/oauth2/token",
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post", "client_secret_jwt", "private_key_jwt"],
  "jwks_uri": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/oauth2/jwks",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/userinfo",
  "response_types_supported": ["code"],
  "grant_types_supported": ["authorization_code", "client_credentials", "refresh_token"],
  "revocation_endpoint": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/oauth2/revoke",
  "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post", "client_secret_jwt", "private_key_jwt"],
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/oauth2/introspect",
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post", "client_secret_jwt", "private_key_jwt"],
  "subject_types_supported": ["public"],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
  "scopes_supported": ["openid"]
}
```

When I am trying to revoke and logout by executing the following code in the action of the Logout button:

```
this._oAuthService.revokeTokenAndLogout({
  client_id: this._oAuthService.clientId,
  returnTo: this._oAuthService.redirectUri
}, true)
```

I can see it is hitting the revoke endpoint `http://auth.myapp-local.mycompany.com:8080/oauth2/revoke`. But it stays on the same page. And if I modify the above code and do this:

```
this._oAuthService.revokeTokenAndLogout({
  client_id: this._oAuthService.clientId,
  returnTo: this._oAuthService.redirectUri
}, true).then(() => this._router.navigateByUrl('/'));
```

Then it is routed to `index.html (AutoLogicComponent)` and stays there.

I would like to route the user to the login page, as well as on clicking the browser's back button after logout, it must not let the user access the protected resource.

What I am unable to figure out, is whether I am missing something or the backend Authorization server does not support the logout functionality yet.

Any pointers or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I personally prefer [`CanActivate` route guards](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/master/src/app/core/auth-guard-with-forced-login.service.ts) (or [without redirection](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/master/src/app/core/auth-guard.service.ts)) to protect pages, which should help with *"clicking the browser's back button"* part